# downloading file fails after 2 mb (php)

Tags: php, timeout, filesize

i want to download a file from a remote server. i already tried fopen etc. without success, so i tried using system /shell and wget but wget also fails after 2000 kb.
are you familiar with this issue of Do you have a clue how to bypass/reset this limitation?

Comment: This happened to me before with `wget`. Never managed to fix it though, I am pretty sure it's the website's fault.

Comment: no errors/exceptions thrown. in the error logs it says that the script ended unexpectedly.

Comment: did you try setting wget with some common user agent?

Comment: no, i didnt. but dont you think that the access might be blocked immediatly Not after ~2mb. iguess it might ne a server config issue and i am just searching for the right config Option.

Comment: Are you downloading from your own server or is this some other server you don't have control over? What is the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the file taking awhile to download? If so you might need to adjust your script timeout in php. Assuming your request isn't a hard timeout from apache, you're going to want to look at your resource limits in php.

Mine look like this:

```
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 120
memory_limit = 128M
```

Answer (score 0):

in php.ini file increases the memory_limit to 12M (for example).